# Binarize image before OCR scan

Tags: java, android, bitmap, ocr, colormatrix

I have an name card scanner app to help in create new contacts which follows the following steps:

1. User take a picture
2. User crop the picture
3. System shows user cropped image to confirm the crop
4. System retrieve cropped picture and run OCR
5. System takes OCR results and populate into the contacts fields (eg, Name, Phone number, Address, etc)
6. User can edit and save contact.

However. now I hope to increase the accuracy of the OCR process to produce better results for the OCR scan.

I have heard of this process which binarize the image and makes it more accurate for the OCR scan.

I am trying to to send my image into this new process in step 3, where system shows user cropped and already binarised image to confirm crop.

After some research, I have found several methods like TextCleaner, ImageMagick and several others. However, I cannot find an implementation on Android. This closest I got is from this link: [Binarize Image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375471/binarize-image-in-android)

However I cannot make the answers from that question work in my codes. I am currently using Android Studio 1.5.1.

My codes are gathered from this link: https://github.com/TheWall89/AndrOCR